# Самопроизвольное выключение бота Discord

Tags: javascript, discord

Я столкнулся с данной проблемой ещё давно, но до сих пор не могу её решить. В чём заключается проблема:Бот со временем сам выключается, не зависит от нагрузки на него и сколько он был включённым, консоль при этом открыта, никаких ошибок нет, просто он тупо выключается, но если в консоли нажать ctrl + `, то с шансом 50% он снова включится, может кто-то сталкивался с этим, как это решить ?

index.js :

```
const Discord             = require("discord.js");             //библиотека Дискорд
const sdr                 = new Discord.Client({disableEveryone: true});     //имя клиент
const config              = require("./config/bconfig.json"); //путь до конфига
const baseMessage         = require('./Module/ModuleDatabase.js'); //база сообщений

const fs                  = require('fs');                    
const sql                 = require("sqlite");              
const moment              = require('moment');        
const chalk               = require('chalk');                  
const money               = require('discord-money');
const ini                 = require('ini');

//Краситили
const GreenStyle          = chalk.green;                       //Зелёный
const RedStyle            = chalk.red;                        //Крассный
const BlueStyle           = chalk.blue;                      //Синий
const YellowStyle         = chalk.yellow;                   //Жёлтый
const MagentaStyle        = chalk.magentaBright;           //серенивый
const GrayStyle           = chalk.gray;                   // серый
const RedBackground       = chalk.bgRed                  // Фон красный
const mathjs              = require('mathjs')
sdr.commands              = new Discord.Collection();     
sdr.commands1              = new Discord.Collection();                  
const talkedRecently      = new Set();                                    
const ErrorCheck          = require('./Module/Error.js') //модуль ошибок

sdr.login(config.token);

process.on('unhandledRejection', error => {
    console.error('Unhandled promise rejection:', error);
});

sdr.on('ready', async () => {
   
    process.on("unhandledRejection", console.error);
    console.log('Я запустился!');
   
console.log(`
╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
║ ${GrayStyle(`• ${sdr.users.cache.size} всего участников`)}
║ ${GrayStyle(`• ${sdr.channels.cache.size} всего каналов`)}
║ ${GrayStyle(`• Бот состоит в: ${sdr.guilds.cache.size} группах`)}
║ ${GrayStyle(`• `)}
║ ${GrayStyle(`• `)}
║ ${GrayStyle(`• `)}
╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
`)
});

//модуль команд
//========================================================================
fs.readdir("./utils/", (err, files) => {

    if(err) console.log(err);
  
    let jsfile = files.filter(f => f.split(".").pop() === "js")
    if(jsfile.length <= 0){
      console.log("Не удалось найти команды.");
      return;
    }
  
    jsfile.forEach((f, i) =>{
      let props = require(`./utils/${f}`);
      sdr.commands.set(props.help.name, props);
    });
  
});

sdr.on("message", async message => {
    if(!message.guild)
    if(message.author.bot) return;
    if(message.author.id == config.SudarID) return;
    if(message.channel.type === "dm") return;
    if(message.content.indexOf(config.prefix) !== 0) return;
    
    let messageArray = message.content.split(" ");
    let cmd = messageArray[0];
    let args = messageArray.slice(1)
    
    let commandfile = sdr.commands.get(cmd.slice(config.prefix.length));
    if(commandfile) commandfile.run(sdr,message,args);


});
```

Я думал дело в {disableEveryone: true}, ибо его вроде убрали в 12 версии, но оказалось нет, после того как нажимаю любую кнопку и бот просыпается, я в debug получаю следующее:

```
[WS => Shard 0] Heartbeat acknowledged, latency of 148ms.
[WS => Shard 0] [HeartbeatTimer] Sending a heartbeat.
[WS => Shard 0] [CLOSE]
    Event Code: 1000
    Clean     : false
    Reason    : No reason received
[WS => Shard 0] Clearing the heartbeat interval.
[WS => Shard 0] WS State: CLOSED
[WS => Manager] Session Limit Information
    Total: 1000
    Remaining: 999
[WS => Shard 0] [CONNECT]
    Gateway    : wss://gateway.discord.gg/
    Version    : 6
    Encoding   : json
    Compression: none
[WS => Shard 0] Setting a HELLO timeout for 20s.
[WS => Shard 0] [CONNECTED] in 240ms
```

Я заметил что эта проблема появляется абсолютно рандомно, если закрыть и открыть консоль то эта проблема может появится уже через минуту, а может через пару дней, я думаю это дело в интернете самом

Comment: Приложите код главного файла, возможно, ошибка в нем

Comment: Я добавил код главного файла